# OpenCV: selection of contours in a processed image

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I'm a newbie in OpenCV, and I want to know if you could select a contour in a processed image, for example, you are detecting 1 circle 2 squares and 1 triangle, and you want to know the distance between the triangle and 1 square right now, so i wish to know if you can select the figures in the processed image with a mouse instance or something like that, also, change the selection, like if i want to know the distance between the circle and square or circle and triangle, something like it. I don't know if I've explained myself, but I would appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: You can find the contours in OpenCV, and you can do some basic GUI things in OpenCV (e.g. have mouse-even callback functions) (see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html). If you want more full-fledged GUIs though, you might be better served by Qt or a dedicated GUI library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible (when you get there) but I'll recommend you split it into baby steps. This project is hard work, it will not happen in one day. I'll recommend scaling it down initially, aiming low and only after completion, to increase the task's complexity:

1. Have a circle, triangle, and square
2. Identify their contours
3. Identify the shape of each object
4. Compute and print out the distance between the centroids of the square and triangle.